# Creating a distribution of random sample means

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

The following is taken from Chapter 19: Distribution of Random Sample Means from the book: *Illuminating Statistical Analysis Using Scenarios and Simulations*.

> Fifty random monkeys, each randomly pick a number from the following list of values.
> 1   2   3   4   5   6   7
> Then you add up the 50 numbers and calculate the sample mean.
> Say you do this 1000 times and put the 1000 sample means in a histogram. What will the histogram look like?

In an attempt to recreate the histogram of the distribution of sample means I tried the following code:

```
Histogram[Table[Mean[RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 7}], 50]], 1000]]
```

My question is: is the above procedure to create a distribution of sample means correct? Is there a better alternative?

P.S. This is not an assignment question. I am just reading the book on my own.

Comment: you can also use  `Histogram[
 Mean@RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 7}], {50, 1000}]]`
`